# ColorPicker material-ui-color, set color on mouse up

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onchange, color-picker

I am using `ColorPicker` from [material-ui-color](https://github.com/mikbry/material-ui-color) and I have a problem with setting value `onChange`.

The issue is that when I start dragging the mouse in `ColorPicker` it constantly calls `onChange`.
I would expect that the moment I stop dragging the mouse it would call `onChange`.

Any ideas on how to accomplish desired result? [Link to CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-color-picker-forked-mgehe?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `useEffect` we can perform actual `setState` or in this case `console.log(color)`, some time (in this case after 0.2 sec) after the user stops dragging the mouse in colorPicker or moving the slider in opacity or etc.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(
      () => {
        if (color != null) {
          //Do your things
          console.log(color);
        }
      },

      200
    );
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [color]);
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-color-picker-forked-mgehe?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `deferred` prop in the `ColorPicker`. With `deferred` set to true, change handler only fires when you click the SET button to commit the change:

```
<ColorPicker value={color} onChange={handleChange} deferred />
```

**EDIT**: If you really really want to listen to the `mouseup` event, you need to do some dirty work using plain JS:

```
function MyColorPicker({ onChange }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [, forceRender] = useReducer((x) => ++x, 0);
  const colorRef = useRef<Color>();
  const handleChange = (newValue: Color) => {
    colorRef.current = newValue;
    forceRender();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let colorGradientEl = null;
    let hueSliderEl = null;
    let alphaSliderEl = null;
    let inputEls = [];
    const handleMouseUp = () => onChange(colorRef.current);

    if (open) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        colorGradientEl = document.querySelector(
          '[data-testid="hsvgradient-color"]'
        );
        hueSliderEl = document.querySelector('[data-testid="hueslider"]');
        alphaSliderEl = document.querySelector('[data-testid="alphaslider"]');
        inputEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("input")];
        const colorPickerPopoverEl = document.querySelector(
          ".ColorPicker-MuiPopover-root"
        );

        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
          mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
            if (mutation.removedNodes) {
              setOpen(false);
            }
            observer.disconnect();
          });
        });

        observer.observe(colorPickerPopoverEl!, { childList: true });
        colorGradientEl?.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
        hueSliderEl?.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
        alphaSliderEl?.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

        inputEls.forEach((el) => {
          el.addEventListener("change", handleMouseUp);
        });
      }, 10);
    }

    return () => {
      colorGradientEl?.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      hueSliderEl?.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      alphaSliderEl?.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

      inputEls.forEach((el) => {
        el.removeEventListener("change", handleMouseUp);
      });
    };
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <ColorPicker
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      value={colorRef.current}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

### Usage

`MyColorPicker` now only fires `change` handler when the user stops dragging the mouse:

```
<MyColorPicker onChange={handleChange} />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: it's not exactly what I want, at the moment I have the same as with deferred, I set value onClose

Comment: @Nikita there is a workaround for that if you're desperate, I'll update the answer.

Comment: NearHuscarl  Yes, please

Comment: @Nikita have a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-color-picker-forked-d3284?file=/src/App.tsx) codesandbox.

Comment: yes, but when I change opacity with slider or changing color also with slider, it doesn’t set the value....

Comment: @Nikita See the updated answer.